Does try_emplace guarantee to not move the key when not emplaced?
When using a std::map or std::unordered_map:
auto [_, emplaced] = map.try_emplace(std::move(key), std::move(value));

if (!emplaced) {
  // can I safely use key here?
}

cppreference says "these functions do not move from rvalue arguments" but this could be interpreted as meaning only the value arguments based on the context.
I tested this in godbolt with GCC and verified that they key was not moved.
But in this context I need to know if the standard guarantees this behavior and I don't know how to find that out.

"these functions do not move from rvalue arguments" but this could be interpreted as meaning only the value arguments based on the context. I don't understand what you say.

@273K The full quote talks specifically about move-only values

I think you're overthinking this. Cppreference also says: "If a key equivalent to k already exists in the container, does nothing.", and the standard says something similar: http://eel.is/c++draft/map.modifiers#4

The std::map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<foo>> in the note is just an example for a move-only value_type. std::map<std::unique_ptr<foo>,std::string> is another. Note that the value type of a map is std::pair<const key_type,mapped_type>.

Rvalue argument doesn't mean a move only value.

@273k i suppose they refer to "these functions do not move from rvalue arguments if the insertion does not happen, which makes it easy to manipulate maps whose values are move-only types, such as ..." and confuse "values" with the "mapped_type".

The standard states:

Effects: If the map already contains an element whose key is equivalent to k, there is no effect.
Otherwise inserts an object of type value_­type constructed with piecewise_­construct, forward_­as_­tuple(k), forward_­as_­tuple(std​::​forward<Args>(args)...).

Moving from k would be an effect. Thus, that not happening is required by the standard.

But in this context I need to know if the standard guarantees this behavior and I don't know how to find that out.

If you are confused by the wording on cppreference, have a look at the actual text in the standard. You might have to read very carefully because the wording is often subtle, but it is meant exactly as it is stated.
